# Unable to get profont to work on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, fonts, ubuntu-font-family

I know it's an issue with the bitmap fonts being disabled by default but I'm unable to get Profont (http://tobiasjung.name/profont/) to work. The best link (http://chrisacheson.net/blog/2009/03/21/how-to-get-profont-working-in-ubuntu/) throws a 404 error.

I've tried to follow various other links that tell me to create a new fixed fonts file but even then profont is not activated.

Any other tips appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps to get them installed:

1. Download the fonts from [here](http://tobiasjung.name/profont/)
2. Run `sudo rm /etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf` to remove that file, in my case I simply moved it to `~/`
3. If you look in `/etc/fonts/conf.avail` you will see these files:

   ```
   70-force-bitmaps.conf
   70-no-bitmaps.conf
   70-yes-bitmaps.conf
   ```

   a. Most are linked to files in the `/etc/fonts/conf.d` directory files.
   b. So we create a symbolic link to `70-yes-bitmaps.conf` from `/etc/fonts/conf.d` with a file named `70-yes-bitmaps.conf`

   - `sudo ln -s /etc/fonts/conf.avail/70-yes-bitmaps.conf /etc/fonts/conf.d/70-yes-bitmaps.conf`
4. Extract and double click on the font files and a window will open and install the fonts.
5. Move the extracted font folder to `~/.fonts` or `/usr/share/fonts` as you wish
6. Set up the permission on the folder == 755, and the fonts files == 644
7. Run `sudo fc-cache -f -v`

**Note: Warning**

Bear in mind though, that there was a good reason to discard bitmap fonts, as it made all sorts of havoc with applications like firefox. 
You can be more prudent by mimicking the behaviour of terminus, and explicitly allowing a specific bitmap font to load instead of a few dozens.

Read: `/etc/fonts/conf.d/README`

**UPDATE**

Steps:

1. Remove the previously added symbolic link, if the first install process was followed else ignore and move to steps two.
2. Move the fonts into `/home/$USER/.local/share/fonts` directory
3. Make sure the owner is you
4. Remove the `70-no-bitmaps.conf` file:

   ```
   sudo mv /etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf ~/
   ```
5. Create another symbolic link in `/etc/fonts/conf.avail`:

   ```
   sudo ln -s /etc/fonts/conf.avail/70-force-bitmaps.conf /etc/fonts/conf.d/70-force-bitmaps.conf
   ```
6. Run `sudo fc-cache -v -f`
7. Open the location in `step 1` and double click on the fonts and they will install automatically.
8. Open `Unity Tweak Tool` ( install if not installed) and check to see it's installed:

   [image]

Source:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=7143817

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=792471

Comment: Tried all the steps but I still just see blocks rather than the actual font. I followed all the steps you mentioned:

Comment: Lets try this, create `~/.local/share/fonts` and move those `.pcf` fonts there make sure you change the owner of the fonts to yourself from root, then run `sudo fc-cache -f -v`

Comment: Tried this as well - no luck. I can share outputs and screenshots if you like

Comment: Well I got them to install on my system so don't know why yours isn't working!

Comment: I can see profont on my system as well. But when you select it, it just shows the bitmap blocks rather than characters. Is that not happening for you?